# HTMLVideoElement fires "resize" on stream resolution change. Is it documented somehow?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-video, webkit

At least in WebKit browsers, when the resolution of a video stream changes, the corresponding `video` element triggers a `resize` event. Is there any documentation available on this? Or any references or discussions? I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: There isn't a lot of documentation on it, just the existence of it [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#events).

Comment: Thank you! This must be the answer. I checked the HTMLVideoElement docs, but not HTMLMediaElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the HTML standard:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-video-videowidth

```
Whenever the natural width or natural height of the video changes [...]
fire an event named resize at the media element.
```